# How to filter based on condition where the result hits come from a certain field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch **bool** query with multiple **should** clauses combining multiple **match** queries on multiple **fields** with different boost values.

say I have 5 fields :

productName / currency / country / identifierNumber

I want to filter my results conditionally with this logic:

- **if** the results(hits) of the bool query would come from a match query on the field (*productName*) **then** Filter by **currency**.
- **if** the results(hits) of the bool query would come from a match query on the field (*identifierNumber*) **then** Do Not Filter By **currency**

  **UPDATE**

```html
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "parameter",
                                "fields": [
                                    "productName.test^8",
                                    "productName.raw^4",
                                    "_all^2",
                                    "Zone^10",
                                    "category^12",
                                    "class^71"
                                ],
                                "fuzziness": "1",
                                "prefix_length": 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "productName.test": {
                                    "query": "parameter",
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "fuzziness": "1",
                                    "prefix_length": 3,
                                    "boost": 1000
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "productName.raw": {
                                    "query": "parameter",
                                    "operator": "or",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                    "prefix_length": 3,
                                    "boost": 10
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "identifierNumber": {
                                    "query": "parameter",
                                    "boost": 3000
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "tic": {
                                    "value": "parameter",
                                    "boost": 30000
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "_all": {
                                    "query": "parameter",
                                    "operator": "or",
                                    "fuzziness": "1",
                                    "prefix_length": 2,
                                    "boost": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "field_value_factor": {
                        "field": "productvalue"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode": "multiply"
        }
    },
    "size": 30,
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        },
        "require_field_match": false
    },
    "post_filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "countryName": "France"
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can achieve that but with multiple should clauses on the specific fields, instead of trying to match on all fields together

Comment: @Val thanks for your comment, can you please provide an example?

Comment: Please show the current query you have

Comment: @Val please see the update, I added the json query

Comment: @Val can you help?